# Adding images to multiple google map infowindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So, as part of an assignment we have to design a map using the Google Maps API which needs to use multiple infowindows and custom markers. I have managed the first two, but I seem to be struggling with the images? Could I simply add the images into the array, and if so, how do I format this properly?

Here is my current code

```
//Beginning of Function
function initialise() {

        //Get mapArea in HTML, create map based around latlong
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapArea'), {
            zoom: 16,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.470639, -2.238996),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        //add array of locations and markers
        var locations = [
            ['Geoffrey Manton Building', 53.469272, -2.237179,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png'],
            ['All Saints Building', 53.471086, -2.238541,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'],
            ['Business and Law Schools', 53.470575, -2.239673,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'],
            ['John Dalton', 53.471964, -2.240392,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'],
        ];

        //declare variable marker as i
        var marker, i;

        //Declare new infowindow for locations
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        //add marker to each location
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
                icon: locations[i][3]
            });

            //Create marker functionality, allow infowindow opening
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);
```

Comment: Where do you want to add these images? Is it supposed to be the marker icon or to be added to the infowindow?

Comment: @MrUpsidown In the infowindows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the images to your array. That'd be fine.

```
var locations = [
    ['Geoffrey Manton Building', 53.469272, -2.237179, 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png', 'http://placehold.it/100x100'],
    ['All Saints Building', 53.471086, -2.238541, 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png', 'http://placehold.it/100x200'],
    ['Business and Law Schools', 53.470575, -2.239673, 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png', 'http://placehold.it/100x50'],
    ['John Dalton', 53.471964, -2.240392, 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png', 'http://placehold.it/200x200']];
```

Then build your infowindow content with whatever HTML markup and information you need from your array:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
    return function () {

        var html = '<h4>' + locations[i][0] + '</h4>';
        html += '<img src="' + locations[i][4] + '" />';

        infowindow.setContent(html);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
})(marker, i));
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/9306de0o/)</kbd>

*Note that I have changed your main function name from `initialise` to `initialize` and you map element id from `mapArea` to `map-canvas`.*